# Updating the location of a sprite on StackPane JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx

I have a question regarding JavaFX. I taught myself Java and now I'm learning JavaFX.

I've been trying to update the location of a 50x50 black block on the screen. I have a YAxis variable that when I change changes the location of the block.

I want the block to "flow" down the screen similar to Tetris.

My code is messy, as I'm just messing around with it, so please excuse that:

```
package gamefx;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GameFX extends Application {

  public Image img = new Image("Block1.png");
  public ImageView image = new ImageView(img);
  public int YAxis = -200;


  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
    StackPane stckp1 = new StackPane();
    Scene scn = new Scene(stckp1, 700, 700);

    primaryStage.setScene(scn);
    primaryStage.show();
    image.setTranslateY(YAxis);
    stckp1.getChildren().add(image);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to see your block moving, you need an animation. See [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm) for more information.

A sample code, quickly written:

```
TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), image);
tt.setByY(yAxis);
tt.setCycleCount(1);
tt.play();
```

*Side-note:* Variable names shall not start with an upper-case letter. Use `yAxis` instead of `YAxis`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped greatly. I also changed the name to yAxis, thanks :)